# mod_rewrite and escaped / (%2f) in query string

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the following url

```
oldsite.com/index.htm?Page?somepath%2fsomefile
```

to

```
newsite.com/productindex.htm?p=somepath%2fsomefile
```

I have the following rules

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.htm$ http://newsite.com?p=%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But it redirects to

```
newsite.com/productindex.htm?p=somepath%252Fsomefile
>--------------------------------------^^^^^
```

There are a lot of references about a long standing bug with double escaping that was recently fixed ([2.2.12 I think](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45529)) and as I am running 2.2.9 I thought the RewriteRule B flag may help, but it makes it worse...

```
newsite.com/productindex.htm?p=somepath%25252Fsomefile
>--------------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

Any ideas from the Apache gurus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the [NE (No Escape)](http://borkweb.com/story/apache-rewrite-cheatsheet#_rewriterule-flags_1) flag that I need

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.htm$ http://newsite.com?p=%1 [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```